# Why's my xpath returning both tables despite specifying the index?

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, web-scraping, xml-parsing

I am using the Fuzi Swift library for parsing [this hackernews page](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19722704).

I need to extract only the top description of the post which contains the main post's details (i.e. "Maybe HN can help solve this little mystery.........low.com/a/55711457/2251982)

Attached screenshot:

[image]

Here's my `xpath` code:

```
print("Description: \(String(describing: document.xpath("//*[@id=\"hnmain\"]//tr[2]/td/table[1]//tr[4]/td").first?.rawXML))")
```

But my output keeps showing both the tables i.e. the top post one as well as the comment table:

```
Description: Optional("<td>Maybe HN can help solve this little mystery. The default font sizes in HTML have, since at least 1998 [1], been .83em and .67em for h5 and h6, respectively, making them smaller than normal text by default (1em). This leads to the bizarre situation that without any styling, the h5 and h6 headings are smaller than the text they head!<p>Does anyone know why headings were made smaller than normal text? I bet the answer is buried in some mailing list from the mid 90s, but so far my searches have not been fruitful. Perhaps someone here was around at the time of, or was even involved in, this decision.<p>[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711457/2251982</p></p>\n        <tr style=\"height:10px\"/><tr><td colspan=\"2\"/><td>\n          <form method=\"post\" action=\"comment\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"parent\" value=\"19722704\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"goto\" value=\"item?id=19722704\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hmac\" value=\"78883e7dccb14e8eed04ba1f3b825085ecd4c545\"><textarea name=\"text\" rows=\"6\" cols=\"60\"/>\n                <br><br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"add comment\"/>\n      </br></br>\n  </input><br><br>\n  <table border=\"0\" class=\"comment-tree\">\n            <tr class=\"athing comtr \" id=\"19725000\"><td>\n            <table border=\"0\">  <tr>    <td class=\"ind\"><img src=\"s.gif\" height=\"1\" width=
```

Why's it selecting the second table too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue. It turns out Fuzi library has bugs and it's xpath resolver isn't working correctly.

I switched to Kanna library and that works great and accurately:

https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

My Kanna code:

```
let myRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19722704")!)

let dataTask : URLSessionTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

    guard error == nil else {
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else {
        return
    }

    if let htmlString = String(bytes: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8), let doc = try? HTML(html: htmlString, encoding: .utf8) {

        for postDescription in doc.xpath("//*[@id=\"hnmain\"]//tr[3]/td/table[1]//tr[4]/td[2]") {
            print("postDescription: \(String(describing: postDescription.content))")
        }

        for comment in doc.xpath("//table[@class=\"comment-tree\"]//tr") {
            print("Comment: \(String(describing: comment.content))")
        }
    }

})
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: This is not a bug of Fuzi, but rather you are using different Xpath queries for them so of course they produced different results.

For Fuzi, the query you used is:

//*[@id=\"hnmain\"]//tr[2]/td/table[1]//tr[4]/td

For Kanna, the query you used is:

//*[@id=\"hnmain\"]//tr[3]/td/table[1]//tr[4]/td[2]

I just tried parsing the page with the second query and both libraries produce the same results.

Answer (score 1):

`//td/table[1]` means select every `table` that is the first child of a `td` element, while `(//td/table)[1]` means select every `table` that is the child of a `td` element, and then from all of these, select the first. Specifically, the operator `x[y]` binds more tightly than `x/y` (or `x//y`), so `x//y[1]` means `x//(y[1])`, not `(x//y)[1]`.

Comment: I tried using `print("Description: \(document.xpath("(//*[@id=\"hnmain\"]//tr[2]/td/table)[1]//tr[4]/td").first?.rawXML)")` but this still gives me both the top and bottom tables. Note I have the parenthesis after table and before the `[1]`. Sorry, I am very new to xpath and not sure what's wrong in this.